# How to restrict a user to a specific directory in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I create two users: `/home/meuser` and `/home/otheruser`

I create a group called workgroup and add the two users to the new group

```
sudo usermod -a -G workgroup meuser
sudo usermod -a -G workgroup otheruser
```

I create a directory `/home/meuser/workarea`, which should be accessible by both users

```
sudo chgrp -R workgroup /home/meuser/workarea
sudo chmod -R 770 /home/meuser/workarea
```

The other user can login and access the `/home/meuser/workarea` directory and see all the files within. But when the other user performs a cd.. the other user is able to get into my directory `/home/meuser`.  How to prevent the user from going up the work area directory and see my directory. Should I create workarea in some other filepath starting `/`, then it requires sudo, which I dont want to give.  If the otheruser performs cd.. it should give a error saying you do not have access or something like that. But other user should be able to go to other user’s home with cd '-'.

Also, I thought there is way to link the common work area directory to the otheruser and let him see the work area directory in his home.

Can you give some suggestions?

Comment: No, you shouldn't "create" anything outside `/home`. Provided one user is in the sudoers list (AKA "admin" or root) and the other isn't it should work. The privileged user (with `sudo`) may "see" everything but the other user is restricted to his/her own userspace. ANY attempt to change this work logic will get you in trouble.

Comment: You don't want to have /home/meuser/workarea - you want to create /home/workarea (or another path.    The problem you are having is that in order to get to /home/meuser/workarea they need access to /home/meuser - You may be able to get away with ensuring the permissions in /home/meuser (excepting /home/myself/workarea) don't allow group access, but that is easy to run afoul of.

Comment: I don't agree with @ChanganAuto (indeed, I've had /media with files that would go into /home save for the fact I want to sync them and have multiple trees/smb mounts - for many years with no issues) - and don't believe sudo is the correct tool for this job.

Comment: @davidgo i created in /home and restrictedmy home directory to 700 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use chroot through sshd. Chroot changes the root directory for a user/group.
They cannot access anything outside this directory.
Append to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Match Group workgroup
    ChrootDirectory /home/meuser/workarea/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

The lines after ChrootDirectory, I believe, are just good practice for this type of thing. AFAIK, they prevent this from being bypassed.
Make sure to restart sshd after changing the config.

Comment: The OP never said ssh is the only scenario that is relevant though.